# Get text from velocity template action in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, velocity

On front I get text from velocity action and I try to put it in js variable:

```
<script>
const text = {
#foreach($resource in ${messages.getResourcesWithPrefix('path.to.keys')})
  '$!{resource.getKey()}': '$!{resource.getValue().replace("'", "")}',
#end
}
</script>
```

The problem arise when the velocity template is loaded and text is in more lines (devided with enter) for example:

```
console.log(text)
//const text = {
//'key1': 'value in one line'
//'key2': 'value in first line❌
//value in second line.'
...
```

Then js error is thrown:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at doc.do)
```

Is it possible to avoid this error on front with JavaScript or it must be done in the back with Java?

BTW if it is loaded directly in html of velocity template, like:

```
#foreach($resource in ${messages.getResourcesWithPrefix('path.to.keys')})
  <div>'$!{resource.getKey()}': '$!{resource.getValue().replace("'", "")}'</div>
#end
```

everything is ok.

Comment: you probably need to JSON encode everything properly

Comment: instead of manually building the object, why not create a DTO and then json encode the DTO with java

Answer (score 0):

The root of your problem is not linked to Velocity, it is that Json strings cannot be multiline.

You need to replace carriage returns with literal '\n' strings, as follow:

```
<script>
const text = {
#foreach($resource in ${messages.getResourcesWithPrefix('path.to.keys')})
  '$!{resource.getKey()}': '$!{resource.getValue().replace("'", "").replaceAll("\n", "\\n")}',
#end
}
</script>
```